# Can similar redux actions be combined?

Tags: redux, ngrx

I have 2 actions that have the same payload and only differ in the type.  Is there a way to combine the two actions such that I don't have redundant code?

`let getData = {type: 'GET_DATA', payload: {id: 1, name: 'sam'}}
 let dataSuccess = {type: 'DATA_SUCCESS', payload: {id: 1, name: 'sam'}}`

Comment: you can define a payload variable and use that in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask question to yourself first that why did you create two separate actions if they are doing the same thing. `type` is only a string to distinguish different actions. If you really need to create two different actions in your case, you can't combine them of course. The only thing you can do probably is to generalize the payload.